# SQL Server - Parser implementation with performance consideration

Tags: sql-server, performance, parsing

I'm implementing a parser that needs to scan potentially long strings (say, up to 200kB) and needs to be as efficient as possible. The strings display a structure that may include hierarchy (for the sake of clarity, let's assume it is a JSON-like string).

The scan process is implemented as a FSM (Finite State Machine) and hence the scan process could be either **capturing** or **bypassing** characters, where both options are handled as a loop that runs till any of a series of possible terminations are found, or the tested character is not present in a list.

For instance, if the scan is running on a number, it will continue till a character is found that is not in the list `'0123456789.+-'`. If the scanning is over a string, it will terminate when the tested character is in the list `'"\''` (where `\` is the escape for `'`). Of course, there are additional lists that may be checked.

So, the logic is (schematically):

```
IF <scan till char NOT IN LIST>
    IF <check if character in list>
        BREAK ;

ELSE -- <scan while char in list>
    IF <check if character NOT in list>
        BREAK ;
```

It is important to note that the tested lists are dynamically built.

I tested so far the following options:

1. User the function `CHARINDEX` such that if it returns `0` the tested character is not in the list, otherwise it is,
2. Split the list of possible characters, insert then into a local table, and use `IF <test char> IN (SELECT ONE_CHAR FROM @_local_Table)...`
3. Build a dynamic SQL command of the form: `SET @_Command = 'SELECT CASE WHEN ''x'' in (''a'',''b'',''c'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'...`

I checked all three alternatives and, though there are some differences in performance, none of them achieve the required response time. Again, this check might need to be performed **thousands of times** while scanning a string.

How can I implement this part in a way that would not impact the overall response time of the parser?

Comment: Hello. What result should parser return? Maybe you should use SQL just for storing result and for complicated logic might use managed code in C# for example ([database engine assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/assemblies/managing-clr-integration-assemblies)) and [GoF pattern interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern)

Comment: Hello @brz, I would rather avoid discussing _where to implement what_. This is (in my opinion) a quite controversial matter and there are many views/opinions around there. As for using a UDF (C#), what I'm developing is a FUNCTION that returns a string (as I wrote, imagine for instance that it is a JSON parser returning the value of an element). As you know, SQL Server enforces severe limitations to the things you can do within a function (very patronizing approach of Microsoft and very regrettable indeed).

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest you use CLR Stored Procedures. It allow SQL Server execute .Net code.
Just create a dll project,and write a method with [SqlProcedure] or [SqlFunction] attribute.

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static int UserDefineFunction(string logstring)
{
    //your code to do the work
}
```

This may increase considerable performance.